# SQL Server 2008 default schema not being respected?

Tags: sql-server, security, schema

We just copied a SQL 2008 database over to another server, for testing purposes. The typical user that logs in uses some objects in a certain schema. Let's say it's user `foo` and schema `bar`.

`foo`'s default schema is `bar` at both the instance and database level. However, when `foo` logs in it can't find any objects in the `bar` schema without using a fully qualified name.

Why wouldn't the default schema work here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Has foo user **sysadmin** rights on SQL Server? Because if it does then any sysadmin user will have by default assigned schema **dbo**, independently of what is set in User's properties for a specific database.

So, in order to have a default schema a user needs to have database roles like db_owner, db_datawriter and so on, instead of server role sysadmin.

Tell me if it'snot your case.

Comment: You are a god and I bow to your knowledge, I was puzzled until I bumped into this!

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario in which this problem may occur (SQL 2008 R2)...

I had a user linked to a SQL Authentication Login, that I was trying to associate with an existing schema.
The Login did not have **sysadmin** rights, so the above solution did not help.

I eventually figured out that the database was still configured in SQL 2000 compatibility mode. Changing to SQL 2005 resolved the issue.

Comment: Strangely, I seem to be having this problem (user linked to a SQL Authentication Login, that I was trying to associate with an existing schema), except my compatibility level is 'SQL Server 2016 (130)'

Answer (score 0):

It will assume that the default schema on the new server is dbo;
If the schema has not been copied with the database.

Not the solution but perhaps this might help, having a look at the msdn article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx

Comment: We have configured the default schema for `foo` on the new server. It is set as `bar` on both the instance user and the database user level.